# AppleScript to add URL to Pi-hole whitelisting

Tags: terminal, applescript, ssh, text-input

I'm writing a script to easily add sites to my Raspberry Pi's Pi-hole installation.

I've got the following:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    reopen
    activate
    do script "ssh pi@192.168.*.*" in window 1
    delay 0.2
    do script "mypassword" in window 1
    delay 0.4
    do script "pihole -w *I need a display dialog where I can put an URL that returns to terminal   
    here* in window 1
    delay 0.2
    do script "exit" in window 1
end tell
```

I want to do this so I do not have to login to my Pi-hole site every other time to block or whitelist some sites.

Answer (score 1):

> Use the `display dialog` command’s optional `default answer` parameter to collect text

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/PromptforText.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH80-SW1

```
set input to display dialog "Enter URL" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
do script "pihole -w " & (text returned of input) in window 1
```

[image]